# SyntaxError: invalid syntax line 138 unexpected error

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I'm facing deep troubles with a script I was trying to write to answer a question on a course  I was doing. I keep on getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax line 138 which was a bit odd. Here is my script. It would be wonderful if somebody could explain how to solve this. Thanks

```
class Message(object):

    def __init__(self, text):

        self.message_text = text
        self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)


    def get_message_text(self):

        return self.message_text


    def get_valid_words(self):

        return self.valid_words[:]

    def build_shift_dict(self, shift):

        lc_str = string.ascii_lowercase
        uc_str = string.ascii_uppercase

        shifted_dict = {}
     
        for ltr in lc_str:
            if lc_str.index(ltr) + shift < 26:
                shifted_dict[ltr] = lc_str[lc_str.index(ltr) + shift]
            else:
                shifted_dict[ltr] = lc_str[lc_str.index(ltr)-26+shift]

        for ltr in uc_str:
            if uc_str.index(ltr) + shift < 26:
                shifted_dict[ltr] = uc_str[uc_str.index(ltr) + shift]
            else:
                shifted_dict[ltr] = uc_str[uc_str.index(ltr)-26+shift]

        return shifted_dict


    def apply_shift(self, shift):

        cipher = self.build_shift_dict(shift)
        ciphertext = ""

        for char in self.message_text:
            if char in cipher:
                ciphertext = ciphertext + cipher[char]
            else:
                ciphertext = ciphertext + char

        return ciphertext
```

Comment: There are far fewer than 138 lines here. Is one of these lines line 138 of your code? If so, could you tell us which?

Comment: Can you give the exact message? We don't know what line 138 is exactly.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide us a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Between these two lines:

```
shifted_dict = {}

for ltr in lc_str:
```

You have a non-ASCII character (`'\xe2'`). Delete it.

(Python tells you exactly this if you try to load your code in a Python interpreter.)